# How to check if an element exist or not before the evaluation

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

the below posted xml file, as shown it has two elements called "tag". and i wrote the below code, to retrieve the values in the "tag" based on the values on the lat and lon.
the problem i am facing now is, despite the xml files i am working on have almost the same structure, some of them have one elemnt called "tag" and others have two elements of the "tag".
and my question is, is there any way using xpath to check inadvance whether an element exists or not before evaluating the expressions?

here is my attempt, but it is not working:

```
"//node/[boolean(tag)]";
"//node/tag[boolean(@following-sibling::tag[1])]";
```

**update**:

```
what i want to do is, to check if the there exist a ::tag[1] and ::tag[2]    
before start evaluating the expression according to the given lat and lon   
"independent of the lat and lon". or in other words, how should i know the 
 number of "tag" exists
```

**xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="25779111" lat="53.0334062" lon="8.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53.0338904" lon="8.846314"/>
<node id="25779119" lat="53.0337395" lon="8.8489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<node id="25779114" lat="53.334062" lon="8.841545"/>
<node id="25779117" lat="53.038904" lon="8.84614"/>
<node id="25779110" lat="53.033795" lon="8.489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="32"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="no"/>
</osm>
```

**code**:

```
private String buildExpression0(double lat, double lon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "//node[@lat='"+lat+"'"+"][@lon='"+lon+"']/following-sibling::tag[1]/@v";
}

private String buildExpression1(double lat, double lon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "//node[@lat='"+lat+"'"+"][@lon='"+lon+"']/following-sibling::tag[2]/@v";
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do in each case? Looking at the 2 methods you posted, can't it be only one method, f.e by saying: get the last tag (2nd tag in case there are 2 tags, and 1st tag otherwise)?

Comment: @har07 kindly please see the update

Answer (score 0):

to know number of `tag` elements in xml, simply evaluate following xpath:

```
count(//tag)
```